# File encoded as Base64 encoded string directly in href attribute for download

Tags: html, base64

If I have a file, for example MS Word document encoded as a Base64 string, is there a way to make it available as a download by putting the string in the href attribute of an A tag along with some MIME info?

Ideally, I would like to do something like...

`<a href="data:Application/base64,UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQDfpNJsWgEAAC[...]"></a>`

[...] being the rest of the string, truncated for readability.

I just need to know if this is worth pursuing or if I'm barking up the wrong tree. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to accomplish what I wanted to do via the following method:

1) I used .htaccess to rewrite the url as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^downloads/(.*)$ file.php?filename=$1 [L,NC]
```

That way my link can point to what appears to be a real file rather than a .php file, so `/downloads/your_file.doc` becomes `/file.php?filename=your_file.doc`.

2) Within `file.php` I set the headers as follows:

```
$filename = $_GET['filename'];
header("Content-type: application/msword"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"); 
echo base64_decode($your_base64_data);
```

Please note that `Content-type: application/msword` is only appropriate for `.doc` files, and you will want to replace this with the appropriate mime type for the file in question, or even make it dynamic by replacing it with a variable if preferred.

I found [this thread](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/decode-base64-file-allow-download-937971.html) very useful in coming to a working solution.